# Making a setup for other Raspberry's

Tags: linux, setup, image, settings, webiopi

I've different versions of Raspberry Pi's 
and want a set of different software on all of them. I made sd-card images and that works fine as long it's the same version of a Raspberry, but when the version is different, the image won't even start.

Is there a way that that I can use a set of software (VPN server, Webiopi, Gspread etc) copy to another Raspberry, without installing and setup each and every program again?

Comment: You could check out config management software like Puppet, chef or ansible, I run puppet on my pi's

Comment: try cloning the sd card using techniques such as: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-clone-your-raspberry-pi-sd-card-for-super-easy-r-1261113524

Comment: Which version of Raspberry Pi did you use for setting up the sd image you want to copy? My experience shows that images working on Raspberry Pi 2 are compatible with the Raspberry Pi 1, but not necessarily the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are using the latest version of Raspbian you should be able to run the same SD Card on different models (at least kernel 4.1.18). I routinely use cloned cards in a B, B+, Pi2 & Pi3 (although the B doesn't get much use lately).

There are a few things to look out for.

If you want to run them simultaneously you should use different `hostname` on each.
Each needs unique IP address.

There are a few things which differ. Serial has changed on Pi3, but if you use `/dev/serial0` it should work on all.

Some distributions e.g. Ubuntu MATE will only work on Pi2 or later.